# ARCH. Choosing a solution to extend a user's session when he is inactive

Tags: .net, single-sign-on, keycloak, openid-connect

First, I want to thank the author of the young GoCloudNative.BFF library - a very useful lib for simply and quickly raising the BFF architecture at your site =)

I have case:

We have pre-authentication from Microsoft (SSO) in our infrastructure. Also, we have keycloak.
In the system, we use BFF. We connect to keycloak via OIDC.

When we access the site (the BFF), the BFF makes a redirect to keycloak.

When we redirect to keycloak, we login to Microsoft via SSO.

A session for the user “Regular SSO” is created in keycloak.
Also, a “Offline” (30-day) user session is created.

Once or twice, we successfully execute the refresh_token.
Then, (after about ten minutes), keycloak gives an error:

```
2023-10-05 08:21:26.1391|48|INFO|Yarp.ReverseProxy.Forwarder.HttpForwarder|RequestCreation: An error was encountered while creating the request message. System.ApplicationException: Unable to retrieve token. OIDC server responded BadRequest: {"error":"invalid_grant","error_description":"Offline user session not found"}
   at GoCloudNative.Bff.Authentication.OpenIdConnect.OpenIdConnectIdentityProvider.RefreshTokenAsync(String refreshToken)
   at GoCloudNative.Bff.Authentication.OpenIdConnect.TokenFactory.RenewAsync[T](String refreshToken, Int32 timeoutInSeconds)
   at GoCloudNative.Bff.Authentication.OpenIdConnect.TokenFactory.RenewAsync[T](String refreshToken, Int32 timeoutInSeconds)
   at GoCloudNative.Bff.Authentication.OpenIdConnect.TokenFactory.RenewAccessTokenIfExpiredAsync[T](Int32 timeoutInSeconds)
   at GoCloudNative.Bff.Authentication.HttpHeaderTransformation`1.<Apply>b__5_0(RequestTransformContext x)
   at Yarp.ReverseProxy.Transforms.Builder.StructuredTransformer.TransformRequestAsync(HttpContext httpContext, HttpRequestMessage proxyRequest, String destinationPrefix, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Yarp.ReverseProxy.Forwarder.HttpForwarder.CreateRequestMessageAsync(HttpContext context, String destinationPrefix, HttpTransformer transformer, ForwarderRequestConfig requestConfig, Boolean isStreamingRequest, ActivityCancellationTokenSource activityToken)
   at Yarp.ReverseProxy.Forwarder.HttpForwarder.SendAsync(HttpContext context, String destinationPrefix, HttpMessageInvoker httpClient, ForwarderRequestConfig requestConfig, HttpTransformer transformer, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
```

Apparently, this happens because the user’s inactivity causes the expiry of the “Regular SSO” session.

The following solutions are being considered:

1 Extend “Regular SSO” by renewing the token. For example, try refresh_token rotation.

2 Extend “Regular SSO” with some artificial user actions. It is not clear how this can be done (token renewal is not considered a user action).

3 Increase the user idle timeout for “Regular SSO” sessions. However, there are many questions, including from information security (IS) side.

4 It is unclear how to update the token using the created “Offline” session... Whether through BFF or Keycloak. It does not seem like a correct solution either.

5 Catch this error in the middleware based on the code (502) and the text (“Offline user session not found”). Then, perform a redirect to Keycloak.

The 5th option seems like the most correct and sufficient. Therefore, I corresponded with the author of the library regarding the issue of expanding its functionality.

However, I would like to know other developers/architects opinions:

Which way would they go?

Which decision is correct in their opinion?

I would like to receive recommendations)